# Increase greater than 0.3 within moving 48 hour window in multiple observations

Tags: r

I have a dataset of hospital records and have to check for the individual patient, if 'creatinine' increases >= 0.3 within 48 hours and if it increases >= 0.3, at which time point the increase is witnessed. My problem is, that the 48 hour interval has to move from the beginning of the record to the end, as the increase could happen in every interval.

Example:

```
dat = data.table(
  patient_id=c(rep(1,7),rep(2,5)),
  measurement=c("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","1","2","3","4","5"),
  t=c("2019-01-19 05:00","2019-01-19 14:00","2019-01-20 05:00","2019-01-20 15:00","2019-01-21 03:00","2019-01-22 05:00","2019-01-23 05:00","2019-01-19 05:00","2019-01-19 14:00","2019-01-20 05:00","2019-01-20 15:00","2019-01-21 03:00"),
  creatinine=c("0.81","0.90","1.00","1.10","1.20","1.30","1.40","0.81","0.90","1.00","1.10","1.20")
)
```

So 48 hour-interval #1 would be measurement 1 to 5. And the first increase of creatinine >= 0.3  would be from measurement 1 to measurement 5. But there could also be no increase in interval #1, so I have to recheck in interval #2 (measurement 2 to 6) for the increase and so on.

I was thinking of determining the min and max of each interval and getting the difference of both, that way I can determine, whether there is an increase >= 0.3 in this interval. However, I have no idea, on how to shift the 48 hour interval from the beginning of the record to the finish.

I hope, my question is clear and I would really appreciate any help or suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `zoo::rollapply` we can find the range for every 5 obs then subtract the upper form the lower to check if it's >=.3

```
library(zoo)
library(dplyr) 
library(tidyr) #nest and unnest functions
library(lubridate) #ymd and hours function
library(purrr) #map function

dat$t<-ymd_hm(dat$t)
dat$two_days<-dat$t+hours(48)

fun_wdate<-function(df){
  #browser()
 apply(df,1, function(y){
       if(y['measurement']==1){
    sum((ymd_hms(y['two_days'])<df$t)=='FALSE')
  } else{
    sum((ymd_hms(y['two_days'])<df$t[-c(1:y['measurement']-1)])=='FALSE')
  }
 })
} 

dat <- dat %>% group_by(patient_id) %>% 
               mutate(width=tibble(measurement,t,two_days)%>%fun_wdate)
#Another option
#dat %>% group_by(patient_id) %>%nest() %>% mutate(width=map(data,~fun_wdate(.))) %>% unnest()

dat %>% group_by(patient_id) %>%
 mutate(Inc=rollapply(as.numeric(creatinine),width, 
 FUN=function(x) (if_else (which.min(x)<which.max(x), range(x)[2]-range(x)[1], range(x)[1]-range(x)[2])),
 align='left',fill=NA), Flag=if_else(Inc>=0.29999,'Yes','No'))
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment! Unfortunately, the number of observations varies between those 48 hour intervals (I forgot to mention this in the orig. post). So I need a method to determine how many and which observations are in each interval.

Comment: @traily here is something not perfect but you can start with. So we try to find the window "width" for each obs then apply `rollapply` using dynamic width.

Comment: @a-suliman thank you so much, that works great with the dynamic width! The only problem I have left is, that if creatinine decreases >= 0.3 it is still calculated as an increase (as the position of min and max are not incorporated). At the moment I'm trying to find a solution to that. Or maybe do you have an idea on how to solve that?

Comment: Ok, now it works as intended: dat <- dat%>%  
  mutate(Inc=rollapply(as.numeric(creatinine),dat$width, FUN=function(x) (if_else (which.min(x)<which.max(x), range(x)[2]-range(x)[1], range(x)[1]-range(x)[2])),align='left',fill=NA), Flag=if_else(Inc>=0.29999,'Yes','No'))

Comment: @traily thanks for accepting the answer. Sorry, now I got your point as  `range(c(1,2,3))==range(c(3,2,1))`. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again. When applying this function to my data, I've noticed, that when I have multiple patients, I need to group them first (eg.use a unique patient identifier) before applying the function for dat$width. Because otherwise, it would calculate the width for every measurement taken in this time period and not only for the specific patient. Unfortunately I'm a total noob to apply & co and was not able to find a way to group my data before applying the function.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  filter(creatinine >= lag(creatinine, 5))
```

If you would have also `Patient_id` column you could do this like this:

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  group_by(Patient_id) %>%
  filter(creatinine >= lag(creatinine, 5)) %>%
  slice(1)
```

`slice(1)` to get only the first occuring 0.3 increase.